# Phonegap - error 404 after build

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to send an HTTP GET request and everything works great while I'm testing. But when I build the application and try to send request, I'm getting 404 error.

Here is my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

    <access origin="*" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://google.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">



            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();


        var start = Date.now();
        var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
                if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                    //alert(Date.now() - start);
                    alert("yeah");

                }
                else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                    alert('There was an error 400');
                }
                else {
                    alert("else: " + xmlhttp.status);
                }
            }
        }


 xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://google.com", true);
 xmlhttp.send();



    </script>
</body>
```

I'm new to PhoneGap and I'm sure this is as simple as it gets, but I can't find anything on google.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `http://myserver/ping` a valid url? Are you sure there isn't a `.com` or a port number or something somewhere in there?

Comment: Yes, It's an open api so I didn't want to post the real url

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you need to set a Content Security Policy meta tag in your index.html as Cordova / PhoneGap 5 or higher will require this.

An example would look like this (in the head section of index.html):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://myserver">
```

Swapping http://myserver for the server you're trying to access.  You may actually be getting error messages such as this in the JS Console if this is your problem:

```
Refused to connect to ‘http://myserver/ping' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: “default-src ‘self’ data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com ‘unsafe-eval’”. Note that ‘connect-src’ was not explicitly set, so ‘default-src’ is used as a fallback.
```

SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.

[This post](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes-a1cde99890df#.xg0zoi4u8) may help with understanding Content Security Policy.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried that but still no luck. I edited my question with updated index.html

Comment: Have you tried hitting the API's URL from the browser on the device / simulator that you are testing the app on - just to make sure that the API is reachable from that device / simulator?  Does remote inspecting the PhoneGap app and having the JS console open show any useful error messages?

Comment: Just noticed you aren't waiting for the "deviceready" event - might be worth amending code to do that and run your XHR after PhoneGap/Cordova is ready.

Comment: Now I'm getting an error "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-P6OhJuaI6AUW6CM8dtsAeG1fSMdb6qAnuGVdihaqkzs='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

Comment: I can't see your index.html with the deviceready event in there, but it looks like you introduced some inline JS somewhere, and will either need to remove that or add 'unsafe-inline' to the default-src so it looks like `    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://google.com">`.  You might want to read up on the CSP to make sure you choose security settings you are comfortable with http://content-security-policy.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here I have assumed that you are using Phonegap version "cli-5.2.0" and facing issue on Android. To fix 404 issue, add following lines in your **config.xml** file

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Whitelist plugin is required to use with Phonegap "cli-5.2.0" to successfully make request to any server.
Link for whitelist plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist